Dimensions of a CBA Velociste
Some years ago I used a bicycle at a rented house, which was a near perfect fit for me. Since then I've struggled to find one as comfortable. I've recently found a couple of the photographs of the bike, which I took for security reasons, and I was hoping that someone might be able to help me in determining the dimensions of the bike.


What kind of dimensions are you looking for? We probably cannot identify the frame size from the photo. Or stem length, but that one is likely the original one. Even if you don't want a professional bike fit, there are many guidelines for finding a bike that fits and is more reliable than recalling a previously ridden bike.

To be more explicit, the same bike with the same name and the same appearance is typically  sold in several sizes. To get any useful dimension information we need to know which size was this one.

Hi Vladimir, thank you for you comments. I was hoping that someone would know of this brand and be able to point me in the direction of a website.

Even then you will need to know which frame size of the bike you were riding. Bikes typically come in several sizes and the website would have dimensions for each size. If you are lucky, most will not show info about such old bikes (but some would).

Start by deciding if it was a 26" or a 27.5" wheel, I suspect the latter but could be wrong.   Then visually measure on the photo from the BB axle up the downtube to the head tube, and to the seatpost clamp.   Scale those to the known wheel size, and you've got some dimensions to work from.
